# best optimum way to create Contact Form 7 WordPress for 4000 + record

Tags: wordpress, contacts, contact-form-7

I am creating a university application form Contact Form I have fixed fields like University Name, Course Name,     Course Level, Field of Study I would like the user to find the courses they want and the can apply directly and press the "Apply now 
" to get the corresponding fields to my Contact Form
I can't create a form for 4000+ plus different rows.

how can I create one unified form and change the base on the steps shown the photo? step 1 then 2 then 3 then 4 then 5

[create one unified form and change the base on the steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQ6Z9.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may check the Contact [Form 7 Conditional Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-conditional-fields/), this will 'switch' the data of each next step(field) based on the choice of the previous one. Still you'll have to manually fill all the necessary data for each field.